# IIS session ends when external process run from ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, session, iis

I have problem during running external process from ASP.NET application.

The process is run as follows:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static WebResult generateSomething(string language)
{
            ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
            psi.UseShellExecute = false;
            psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
            psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
            psi.ErrorDialog = false;
            psi.WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
            psi.FileName = String.Format("\"{0}\"", Path.Combine(appDir, Properties.Settings.Default.PATH_TO_APP_TEXT));
            psi.Arguments = arguments.ToString();

            modeller.log.Info("Arguments: " + psi.Arguments);

            var outputText = new StringBuilder();
            int exitCode;

            var result = new WebResult();

            using (Process process = new Process())
            {
                process.StartInfo = psi;
                process.OutputDataReceived += (sendingProcess, args) => { outputText.Append(args.Data); };
                process.ErrorDataReceived += (sendingProcess, args) => { outputText.Append(args.Data); };
                process.Start();
                process.BeginOutputReadLine();
                process.BeginErrorReadLine();
                process.WaitForExit();
                exitCode = process.ExitCode;
            }

            string outText = outputText.ToString();
```

Immediately after process finishes (succesfully or not) and the method leaves ASP.NET IIS session is ended, so any authentication context via cookie breaks.

Can anyone help with this issue?
Thanks in advance